# Error with onPreferenceChange

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is the file that I am getting the error getSummary() in Preference cannot be applied to (java.lang.CharSequence) on preference.getSummary(listPreference.getEntries()... and also an error with the same getSummary() (java.lang.String) on the else statement.

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key)));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference){
    //set listener to watch for value change
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    //Trigger the listenter immediately with the preferences current value
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value){
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        //look up the correct display value in the preferences enteries list
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.getSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }

    }
    else{
            preference.getSummary(stringValue);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getSummary() *returns* the summary, it takes no arguments.

You're most likely looking for setSumary(CharSequence summary)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary(java.lang.CharSequence)